# I'm creating a program that take five input from user and display the largest by using another function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I created the program that take an input from a user using an array of type int,, and the i want to use a user define function to display the largest element in the array, 
The problem is that i passed the array through the function but it didn't show me the largest element

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 5
void get_max(int list[size]);
int main()
{
    int list[size];
    printf("Enter five numbers : ");
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("Element in array list[%d] = %d\n",i,list[i]);
    }
    get_max(list[size]);
}

void get_max(int list[size])
{
    int large,i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(large < list[size])
        {
            large=list[size];
        }

    }
    printf("\nLargest element in array list  %d",large);
}
```

I want to print the largest value in the elements after getting the input from the user,,,,

thanks

Comment: instead of `if(large < list[size])` you probably thought about `if(large < list[i])`

Comment: Also initialize `large` while declaring.

Comment: @kiranBiradar  ,, after running the program and getting the input ,it didn't work and not showing me the value

Comment: Sometimes you use `size` and sometimes 5; this will be very confusing if you decide to change the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly there are three errors in your code.

1. You are calling the function with  `get_max(list[size]);` instead of     `get_max(list);`. When you give `list[size]` as argument, it points to the 6th element (list[5] array index start from 0 - size-1). So two errors are there itself. There is no 6th element and array will go out of bounds which can cause undefined behaviour. Also, even if you meant `list[4]` then there is a logical error i.e you are passing the address of the last element of the array. So it will definitely go out of bounds and cause undefined behaviour inside your function. `get_max(list);` is the correct way to do it.
2. You have used `large=list[size]` inside `get_max()` function which will create undefined behaviour as explained in first point.(array index starts from 0 i.e 0-(size-1) is the valid accesses).
   eg:    `if(large < list[size])` has an undefined behaviour. It should be `list[i]` in the program. You have to iterate through all array elements to find the largest number.
3. Variable `large` is undefined. You should set it before the `if(large < list[size])` otherwise it can cause undefined behaviour in your application. So set `large=list[0]`.

One additional hint is when you are trying to find the largest (or smallest) number you should set `large=list[0]` (or any element in the input array) as in below code. Otherwise if you set `large=0` initially and if all the input numbers are negative, then the program will output wrong result.

Fixing the above errors will make your code run. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 5
void get_max(int list[size]);
int main()
{
    int list[size];
    printf("Enter five numbers : ");
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("Element in array list[%d] = %d\n",i,list[i]);
    }
    get_max(list);
}

void get_max(int list[size])
{
    int large,i;
    large=list[0];
    for (i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(large < list[i])
        {
            large=list[i];
        }

    }
    printf("\nLargest element in array list  %d",large);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `large` is uninitialized and will have indeterminate value which will effect your caclucation.
2. Accessing `list[size]` is undefined behavior, probably you meant `list[i]`.

```
    void get_max(int list[size])
    {
        int large = 0,i = 0;
        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(large < list[i])
            {
                large=list[i];
            }

        }
        printf("\nLargest element in array list  %d",large);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call get_max... As a parameter you have to put only list, not list[size]...
An

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you able to amend this answer to show us your full solution? Thanks!